# Timeout while triggering AWS EMR flow step from AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-emr

I am trying to run an AWS lambda application in JavaScript, but I can't make it work properly.
I don't have any troubles with the JS configuration and triggering (I successfully runned a hello world app), but I'm experiencing problems with the aws-sdk library. To be honest, I don't know if this is a problem related to network configuration or to IAM configuration, but I'm pretty sure it's not a scripting issue, because I can run it without any problem locally in my computer.
The main problem I have is that when the lambda app calls the AWS EMR API, there is a timeout error. It's like lambda is not able to communicate to EMR.

Here, you can see the emr client (`console.log(emr_client)`):

```
  emr: Service {
    config: 
     Config {
       credentials: 
        EnvironmentCredentials {
          expired: false,
          expireTime: null,
          accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          sessionToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          envPrefix: 'AWS' },
       credentialProvider: CredentialProviderChain { providers: [Array] },
       region: 'us-west-2',
       logger: null,
       apiVersions: {},
       apiVersion: '2009-03-31',
       endpoint: 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
       httpOptions: { timeout: 120000 },
       maxRetries: undefined,
       maxRedirects: 10,
       paramValidation: true,
       sslEnabled: true,
       s3ForcePathStyle: false,
       s3BucketEndpoint: false,
       s3DisableBodySigning: true,
       computeChecksums: true,
       convertResponseTypes: true,
       correctClockSkew: false,
       customUserAgent: null,
       dynamoDbCrc32: true,
       systemClockOffset: 0,
       signatureVersion: 'v4',
       signatureCache: true,
       retryDelayOptions: {},
       useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
       accesKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' },
    isGlobalEndpoint: false,
    endpoint: 
     Endpoint {
       protocol: 'https:',
       host: 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
       port: 443,
       hostname: 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
       pathname: '/',
       path: '/',
       href: 'https://elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/' },
    _clientId: 1 
    }
```

Some AWS config information:

1. I created a VPC where my EMR cluster resides, located in us-west-2 region, and I'm triggering the lambda function there (as I can confirm consoling `process.env.AWS_REGION`).
2. I setted up a subnet that was previously created inside this same VPC. The EMR cluster is inside it and the Lambda function has access to it.
3. I setted up a security group in this same VPC with all inbounds/outbounds allowed (all ports from and to 0.0.0.0/0) to see if I had a configuration problem there.
4. I setted up an execution role that has the following policies attached and linked it with my lambda function:

> AWSLambdaFullAccess
>
> AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess
>
> AWSLambdaExecute
>
> AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
>
> AWSLambdaRole
>
> AWSLambdaENIManagementAccess

Finally, my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const emr = new AWS.EMR({
    apiVersion:'2009-03-31',
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  });

  const flowSteps = {
    JobFlowId: process.env['JOB_FLOW_ID'],
    Steps: [{
      Name: "my_beautiful_step",
      ActionOnFailure: "CANCEL_AND_WAIT",
      HadoopJarStep: {
        Jar: "command-runner.jar",
        Args: [
          "spark-submit",
          "--master"," yarn",
          ...
          ...
          ...
        ]
      }
    }]
  };

  emr.addJobFlowSteps(flowSteps, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('ERROR', err, err.stack);
    } else {
      console.log('NO ERROR', data);
    }
  });

};
```

**EDIT:**
I tried communicating to s3 (getting a bucket location) just to test if the problem was only with EMR, but the function also timouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved my issue. Basically, you can't call AWS API endpoints inside a VPC if you don't have internet access, because most of the aws services have a public URL, e.g., `https://elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`. You can clearly see this when you console the EMR client object (and this applies too for other client objects such as S3 as I verified)

```
Service {
  config: 
   Config {
     ...
     ...
     region: 'us-west-2',
     logger: null,
     apiVersions: {},
     apiVersion: null,
     endpoint: 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
     httpOptions: { timeout: 120000 },
     maxRetries: undefined,
   },
  endpoint: 
   Endpoint {
     protocol: 'https:',
     host: 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
     port: 443,
     hostname: 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
     pathname: '/',
     path: '/',
     href: 'https://elasticmapreduce.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/' 
    },
  ...
}
```

Anyways, AWS provides some local endpoints inside vpcs [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) so you can access to those services endpoints inside the VPC without internet access. In another case, you have to set a NAT gateway + internet gateway (~u$s 30/month) to access to other services such as EMR.